# How can I assign a certain icon to a database value?

Tags: html, css, database, icons, font-awesome

I'm working with a data base that tells me if the user is a male (displays the "M" letter) or if is a woman (displays the "F" letter). I wanted to display the venus/mars icon depending on the gender instead of the letter itself (if is "M" the mars icon appears, if is "F" the venus icon appears). How can I do this?

Here is how I get the value from the data base :

```
<div class="gender" data-bind="text:Sex"></div>
```

PS: I am working with font awesome icons.

I tried assigning the font awesome icons but I'm not doing it right.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using JS DOM. Just add class M or F it will automatic add fontawesome icon

```
<div class="gender m" data-bind="text:Sex"></div>

<script>
    if (document.querySelector(".gender.M")) {
        document.querySelector(".gender").innerHTML = `<i class="fa-solid fa-mars"></i>`;
    }
    else {
        document.querySelector(".gender").innerHTML = `<i class="fa-solid fa-venus"></i>`;
    }
</script>
```